# Clickable link within a div circle

Tags: html, css

I am VERY new to working with HTML and CSS; looking to craft four colored circles with some text inside their borders which will link to a website. Currently using the following:

```
<div id="first" class="circle"></div>
<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test One</button>

<div id="second" class="circle"></div>

<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test Two</button>

<div id="third" class="circle"></div>

<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test Three</button>

<div id="fourth" class="circle"></div>
<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test Four</button>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.circle{
position:absolute;
width:150px;
height: 150px;

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
filter: alpha(opacity=30);
-moz-opacity: 0.3;
-khtml-opacity: 0.3;
opacity:0.3;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid black;
}


#second{position:relative; left:120px; top:2px;
 background: orange;

}

#first {
background: blue;

}




#third {
position: relative; 
top: -40px;
left: 0px;
background: red;
}
#fourth {
position: relative; 
top: -190px;
left: 120px;
background: green;
}
}

#problem{
font-size: 8pt;
color:white;
position: absolute;
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
border-left:2px solid red;
border-top:2px solid red;
top : 41px;
left:71px;
z-index:-4;
background:red;
}
#problem:after{
position:absolute;
content:" ";
background:white;
width:150px;
height:150px;
top:-2px;
left: -2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
z-index:-3;
}
```

I am having trouble getting the text links to conform to the interior of the circles. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Clickable elements that link to new pages or sites should be `<a>` elements, not `<button>` elements.

Comment: Validate your code, your use of HREF and ONCLICK are incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to convert your divs into anchor tags. So it would look something like this:

```
<a id="first" href="https://taikoinitiative.com" class="circle"></a>

<a href="https://taikoinitiative.com" id="second" class="circle"></a>

<a href="https://taikoinitiative.com" id="third" class="circle"></a>

<a href="https://taikoinitiative.com" id="fourth" class="circle"></a>
```

Which would then give you a circle that, when clicked, will take you to the link provided

Answer (score 0):

All the `<button>` elements should go inside their respective `<div>` elements. Try this html code.

```
<div id="first" class="circle">
<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test One</button>
</div>

<div id="second" class="circle">
<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test Two</button>
</div>

<div id="third" class="circle">
<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test Three</button>
</div>

<div id="fourth" class="circle">
<button onclick="href="https://taikoinitiative.com>Test Four</button>
</div>
```

And set position of all the selectors `#first`, `#second`, `#third` and `#fourth` to absolute instead of relative.

```
#first {position: absolute;}
```

and same for others.

Comment: Check your code. Your ONCLICK and HREFs are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax it works:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <a href="Your link" class="class name">Button Name</a>
     <a href="Your link" class="class name">Button Name</a>
     <a href="Your link" class="class name">Button Name</a>
     <a href="Your link" class="class name">Button Name</a>
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you are trying to place 4 circles that will link to some pages. For linking pages we use the anchor `<a>` tag with `href` attribute. Putting `<a>` tags inside `<div>` tags helps in styling and removes the need for absolute positioning.

You can convert your code as follows:-

```
<div id="first" class="circle">
    <a href="https://taikoinitiative.com">Test One</a>
</div>

<div id="second" class="circle">
    <a href="https://taikoinitiative.com">Test Two</a>
</div>

<div id="third" class="circle">
    <a href="https://taikoinitiative.com">Test Three</a>
</div>

<div id="fourth" class="circle">
    <a href="https://taikoinitiative.com">Test Four</a>
</div>
```

CSS :-

```
a, a:visited, a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.circle{
  padding: 1rem;
  width: max-content;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid thin #ccc;
}

#first{
  background-color: blue;
}

#second{
  background-color: red;
}

#third{
  background-color: orange;
}

#fourth{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Output:-

[JS Fiddle output](https://jsfiddle.net/rtcke73q/)